# Sikuli IDE Error - javax.script.ScriptException " is not defined in nashorn:mozilla_compat.js at line number 69

Tags: sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I'm working on a simple Sikuli Script.

The script is simply one line shown below

click([image])

The following error is produced?

javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Commands" is not defined in nashorn:mozilla_compat.js at line number 69

I believe I have all dependencies installed. Could I ask for some assistance for what else is missing to move on from this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the commands in javascript mode. Do the following: create a new tab, right click on it, select "set type" and choose "jython". Your code should now work.